# File upload using php mysql and saving the filename column wise in db

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am trying to do a upload script. There are 5 file html tags.

The DB structure is as follows:

```
id | attachment_1 | attachment_2, attachment_3, attachment_4, attachment_5
```

I know its not a good db structure, am trying to correct an already developed application. The attachment db structure is column wise. When i upload the file name has to be saved in each respective column and the file has to be saved in UPLOAD folder. Any help appreciated to start with.

Comment: Too broad for SO's QA format I'm afraid - you'd be best off starting with the manual on [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Yeah i understand. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have a short explanation:

I believe, You already know how to upload a file using php.

Have a choose file box in your page with multiple select option. 
Use a form with action = "Link to your functional page"
On your functional page write a code to upload the files.

......

Now if you let users to upload only 5 files then use a for loop or foreach looping.

Now count the number of uploaded files from your form. 
-Use the algorithm

```
Foreach (number of files as $key => $files) // Here $key starts from 0 if not make a variable from 0 and increase its number
    INSERT INTO table_name (attachment_."$key")
     VALUES ($file->filename) WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: Thanx will test it out.